# Multiple headers in accordion

Tags: c#

I have an accordion in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Accordion ID="acrdOdlLeadActivities" runat="server" 
                                SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
                                ContentCssClass="accordionContent" AutoSize="None"
                                FadeTransitions="true" ></asp:Accordion>
```

I need to add multiple header in accordion

```
acdpne.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(objLead.strLeadStatus + i));
acdpne.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(objLead.strSalesManName + i));
```

How can I seperate "strLeadStatus"  and "strSalesManName " (add space between them or give style for it)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either:

- Adding a third literal control between them, you know or....
- Putting together astring as you want it and then add this as a LiteralControl?